# Custom binary file format serializer

Tags: c++, c++20

I am creating a binary file format to store a series of vectors alongside some metadata. The vectors will be stored at the start of the file which will have a predetermined size, and the metadata alongside the size of each vector will go to the end.

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}}
metadata = {'1011', '1110'}

file:
-->
1235670000
0000000000
0000000000
3111031011
       <--
```

So every time I need a new vector I will read the next available metadata block and size, e.g., `31011`, that tells me I need to get **3** items from the current position at the top of the file and so I will end up returning `({1, 2, 3}, '1011')`

The idea I want to test is if storing all my data in contiguous memory addresses will take advantage of caching and speed things up a bit if I have a very large amount of vectors to be used by an off memory algorithm.

My implementation is a `.h` file containing my class:

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <bitset>

class BinaryFile {
public:
    // TODO: metadataWritePos_{static_cast<std::streamoff>(maxFileSize - metadataSize_ - 1)}, am I wasting one bit?
    // TODO: store the number of vectors in the file to resume write/read from a different instance
    BinaryFile(std::string filename, std::size_t maxFileSize, std::size_t metadataSize)
            : filename_{std::move(filename)}, maxFileSize_{maxFileSize},
              metadataSize_{metadataSize + sizeof(long)},
              metadataWritePos_{static_cast<std::streamoff>(maxFileSize - metadataSize_)},
              metadataReadPos_{static_cast<std::streamoff>(maxFileSize - metadataSize_)} {
        file_.open(filename_, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
        if (!file_.is_open()) {
            // If the file does not exist, create it.
            file_.open(filename_, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
            file_.close();
            // Re-open the file in binary mode for both reading and writing.
            file_.open(filename_, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
        }
    }

    // TODO: accept a vector of `T` as the data type.
    template <std::size_t N>
    bool write(const std::vector<int> &data, std::bitset<N> metadata) {
        if (file_.is_open()) {
            // Check if there is enough space at the beginning and end of the file.
            const auto dataSize = data.size() * sizeof(int);
            const auto totalSize = dataSize + metadataSize_;
            const auto curPos = dataWritePos_;
            const auto spaceAvailable = static_cast<std::size_t>(metadataWritePos_ - curPos);
            if (spaceAvailable < totalSize) {
                return false;
            }

            // Write the data to the file.
            file_.seekp(curPos);
            file_.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data.data()), static_cast<std::streamoff>(dataSize));

            // Write the metadata to the end of the file.
            const std::streampos metadataPos = metadataWritePos_;
            file_.seekp(metadataPos);
            file_.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&metadata), static_cast<std::streamoff>(metadataSize_ - sizeof(long)));
            file_.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&dataSize), sizeof(long));

            // Update the data & metadata position for the next write.
            metadataWritePos_ -= static_cast<std::streamoff>(metadataSize_);
            dataWritePos_ += static_cast<std::streamoff>(dataSize);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template <std::size_t N>
    std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::bitset<N>> readNext() {
        std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::bitset<N>> result;
        if (file_.is_open()) {
            const std::streampos curPos = file_.tellg();
            if (metadataWritePos_ <= metadataReadPos_) {
                // Read the metadata hash and vector size from the end of the file.
                std::size_t dataSize;
                const auto metadataPos = metadataReadPos_;
                file_.seekg(metadataPos);
                file_.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&result.second), static_cast<std::streamoff>(metadataSize_ - sizeof(long)));
                file_.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&dataSize), sizeof(long));

                // Read the data from the current position.
                const std::size_t elementCount = dataSize / sizeof(int);
                result.first.resize(elementCount);
                file_.seekg(dataReadPos_);
                file_.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(std::get<0>(result).data()), static_cast<std::streamoff>(dataSize));

                // Update the metadata position for the next read.
                metadataReadPos_ -= static_cast<std::streamoff>(metadataSize_);
                dataReadPos_ += static_cast<std::streamoff>(dataSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // TODO: is there a better way to keep track of these values between instance?
    std::streamoff getLastWritenPosition() const {
        return metadataWritePos_;
    }

    void setLastWritenPosition(std::streamoff pos) {
        metadataWritePos_ = pos;
    }

private:
    std::string filename_;
    std::size_t maxFileSize_;
    std::size_t metadataSize_;
    std::streamoff metadataWritePos_;
    std::streamoff metadataReadPos_;
    std::streamoff dataWritePos_{};
    std::streamoff dataReadPos_{};
    std::fstream file_;
};
```

and I am using it in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

#include "serializer.h"

#define HASH_SIZE 4

void test_write_multiple() {
    // Create a binary writer with some data.
    const std::string filename = "test.bin";
    const std::size_t maxFileSize = 1024;
    BinaryFile writer(filename, maxFileSize, sizeof(std::bitset<HASH_SIZE>));

    const std::vector<std::vector<int>> data = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9},
            {3, 2, 1}
    };
    const std::vector<std::bitset<HASH_SIZE>> metadata = {
            std::bitset<4>("0101"),  // equivalent to decimal value 5
            std::bitset<4>("1100"),  // equivalent to decimal value 12
            std::bitset<4>("0000"),  // equivalent to decimal value 0
            std::bitset<4>("1111")   // equivalent to decimal value 15
    };

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        if (!writer.write(data[i], metadata[i])) {
            std::cout << "::Write failed due to max writer size.\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    // Create a reader to get the original data back.
    BinaryFile reader(filename, maxFileSize, sizeof(std::bitset<HASH_SIZE>));
    reader.setLastWritenPosition(writer.getLastWritenPosition());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        const auto [readData, readMetadata] = reader.readNext<HASH_SIZE>();
        // Check that the read data matches the original data.
        if (readData != data[i]) {
            std::cout << "::Read data does not match original data.\n";
            return;
        }

        // Check that the read metadata matches the original metadata.
        if (readMetadata != metadata[i]) {
            std::cout << "::Read metadata does not match original metadata.\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Multiple write test done.\n";
}
```

Are there any obvious mistakes, any optimizations I could have performed. Is the design even any good, or should I structure the class and the data it handles differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to create unit tests for this code, as we can't separate out the use of actual filesystem files from the logic.

A more testable implementation would accept an open seekable stream, so that we could use a string-stream in the unit tests.  That's something we'd naturally end up with if we wrote some tests before starting the implementation.

Speaking of file streams, I can't see where we check that writes and reads are successful.  We seem to report success if the file can be merely *opened*, regardless of whether any subsequent operations succeed or not.  Perhaps we should be calling the stream's `exceptions()` to cause it to throw on failure?

Comment: It doesn't even report an error if the file could not be opened, it just calls `open()` twice more if it couldn't `open()` the first time, because it assumes it was because the file didn't exist. This is a bad idea. Given that it probably isn't safe to mix calls to `write()` and `readNext()` anyway, I think it's better to split this into two classes; one that only reads (and takes a `std::istream&` in the constructor), and once that only writes (and takes a `std::ostream&`).

Comment: @G.Sliepen I couldn't think of anything better at the time. But this is something I need to improve for sure.

Comment: @toby-speight OK got it, instead of opening and closing a file I should accept a seekable stream. I tried to have the user of the class handle as few things as possible, but what you are saying kind of makes sense.

Comment: There's nothing to prevent you doing both - it doesn't harm to also provide an overload that accepts a filename (which then opens the file and if successful calls the version that accepts a stream).